# Get the date that Windows 10 or 11 was RE-activated with a different license key

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, windows-activation, software-activation

On a Windows 10 or 11 system that has been re-activated with a NEW and different license key some time long after the initial OS install...

How can I find out what date it was most recently RE-activated with the new/current license key?

Comment: What research have you done? Does activating write something to Event Viewer perhaps? What are the circumstances under which an existing install is being reactivated using a different key? What problem are you trying to solve, or underlying question you're trying to answer, with this information? Is this a single, personal computer, or a business environment?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly? Why do you need to know the activation date?

Answer (score 0):

"Activation" is an online procedure, where the computer's hardware environment
is recorded and sent along with the License key to the Microsoft
license servers. With this information, Microsoft can identify the
computer for as long as it exists.

Each time Windows starts up, the computer checks itself against the Microsoft
license servers to see if it's still activated and to update the hardware
hash, in case some hardware was replaced. Too large hardware changes
will require re-activation.

There is no way to ascertain when a specific product key was activated
from your end. That information resides on the Microsoft servers and
there is no way that I know of to get it. Microsoft Support might be
able to answer the question, but not sure that they will do it for free.

For cases where Windows 10 was activated on the installation date of
Windows, you can find this date by running CMD as Administrator
and entering the command `systeminfo`.
The date will be found in the field "Original Install Date".